# C - How to check if 8 bits are in 32 bit?

Tags: c, char, int, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I want to check if the 8 bits in a `char` are a substring of the 32 bits of an `int`.

```
a = 0110 1010 1011 0100 0000 0110 1010 0010 (32 bit int)
b = 0100 0000 (8 bit char)

is_in(a, b) --> true
```

Here is my code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
       int tmp = a;
       tmp <<= 24;
       tmp >>= 24;
       int res = b ^ tmp;
       res <<= 24;
       res >>= 24;
       if (res == 0)
          return 1;
       else
          a >>= 1;
    }
    return 0;
```

I want it more efficient.
Any idea?

Comment: Can `b` be anywhere "in" `a`, or only on byte-boundaries? And what have you tried so far? What problems have you encountered with your code?

Comment: Keywords: shift, mask and compare. Use `<<` or `>>` operators and `&` operator. Come up with a solution and then ask questions when you have difficulties.

Comment: If the 8 bits could be only on a determined position of the 32bit int, you can zero out all the others with AND operations and compare the values directly.

Comment: 8 bits can be anywhere in 32 bit, I updated question with my code.

Comment: If the code actually works as intended, it may be  a better fit for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could try...

```
bool is_in(uint32_t a, uint8_t b) {
  while (a >= b) {
    if ((a & 0xff) == b) return true;
    a >>= 1;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for using `unsigned` for both args, otherwise you end up with 1's being shifted in.

Comment: The obvious solution.

Comment: Downvote for using unspecified width types. There is no guarantee `unsigned` will have 32 bits. Use `stdint.h` types!

Comment: @dbush: Shifting signed types right does not guarantee keeping the sign bit. This is implementation defined (but, yes, that is to be avoided).

Comment: I think this will fail in some cases, e.g. `a = 0x000000ff`, `b = 0xff`, or  `a = 0x0000ff00`, `b = 0xff`. The general idea is good but the bugs need to be fixed.

Comment: The `while(a > b)` will fail when `a` is equal to `b`, which are a subset of the cases you want to detect, i.e. all instances when `b` is the most significant non-zero substring of `a`.  This should be `while(a >= b)` to cover the cases highlighted by @PaulR.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out its flaws. I've incorporated suggested fixes (unfortunately not able to test them now)

Comment: Yes, I think the change from `>` to `>=` should do the job - looks good now.